# Splitting a value in a json object and passing one part of that value to another key in the same object - javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json file with shipping information and in the in the first address line I have an app number and the street address separated by "-". I need to split them and place the app number in the second address line.

Here is the example of the object:

```js
{
    "id": 34853873935,
    "shipping_address": {
        "address1": "944-3555 street name",
        "address2": "",
        "city": "City",
        "company": null,
        "country": "Country",
        "country_code": "Code",
        "first_name": "first",
        "last_name": "last",
        "latitude": 45.4966417,
        "longitude": -73.5848221,
        "name": "name",
        "phone": null,
        "province": "province",
        "province_code": "code",
        "zip": "zip"
    }
```

Comment: shipping_address. address2 = shipping_address. address1.split(" ")[0].split("-")[0]

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

- get the substring of address1 until the first space
- split the result, using - as separator
- get the first element of the result
- prepend it at the start of address2

```
    var obj = {
        "id": 34853873935,
        "shipping_address": {
            "address1": "944-3555 street name",
            "address2": "",
            "city": "City",
            "company": null,
            "country": "Country",
            "country_code": "Code",
            "first_name": "first",
            "last_name": "last",
            "latitude": 45.4966417,
            "longitude": -73.5848221,
            "name": "name",
            "phone": null,
            "province": "province",
            "province_code": "code",
            "zip": "zip"
        }
    };
    obj.shipping_address.address2 = obj.shipping_address.address1.substring(0, obj.shipping_address.address1.indexOf(" ")).split("-")[0] + (obj.shipping_address.address2 ? (" " + obj.shipping_address.address2) : "");
    console.log(obj.shipping_address.address2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
const shipping = {
"id": 34853873935,
"shipping_address": {
    "address1": "944-3555 street name",
    "address2": "",
    "city": "City",
    "company": null,
    "country": "Country",
    "country_code": "Code",
    "first_name": "first",
    "last_name": "last",
    "latitude": 45.4966417,
    "longitude": -73.5848221,
    "name": "name",
    "phone": null,
    "province": "province",
    "province_code": "code",
    "zip": "zip"
}}
```

---

Here you can [destructuring](https://regexr.com/53apa) your object to extract an address1 variable or another's variables.

```
const { address1 } = shipping.shipping_address;
```

---

You can use a [Regex](https://regexr.com/53apa) where the first group captures a set of numeric characters at the beginning and before the "-" sign, and then extract a substring using the $1 assignment.

Then, in the second group, the capture of characters that meet the condition indicated in square brackets is omitted.

```
shipping.shipping_address.address2 = address1.replace(/^(\d{0,})(?:[-\d\w ]{0,})/gi, "$1");
```

---

**output in console:**

```
console.log(shipping)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What if I also want to delete the app from the address1 but keep it on address2. Thanks!

Comment: You welcome, if you want to delete the address1 you can use this code: 
shipping.shipping_address.address1 = address1.replace(/^(?:\d{0,}-)([\d\w ]{0,})/gi, "$1");